# How do I solve the given errror running res.raise_for_status(). I am trying to parsing the HTML from Amazon

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

While running the line >>> res.raise_for_status() I got traceback error.

```
Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14 2019, 19:21:23) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import bs4
>>> import requests
>>> res = requests.get('http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1593275994/')
>>> res.raise_for_status()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
res.raise_for_status()
File "C:\Users\Prashant Shrestha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site- 
packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable for URL: 
https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1593275994/
```

Comment: `raise_for_status()`return that output, your script works fine. [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Comment: _To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com._

Answer (score 0):

Amazon updated its security so **scraping** bots can't access to this information. Try doing this same thing with an ebay page.